# Javascript / node.js - returning the value to parent function

Tags: javascript, node.js

as a node.js newbie, I'm having problems to understand how to return value of nested function. I'm trying to make a function that retrieve data from DB and returns it. Here is my code:

```
getRecent: function() {

    var promise = models.download.find({}).sort({date_added: -1}).limit(5).exec();

    promise.then(function(data) {
        return data;
    });

}
```

My goal is to get the function getRecent() return the data from mongo. My initial ideas were:

1. make variable for the data, assing the data in the promise function and then return the variable
2. make something like this:

   ```
   var test = promise.then(function(data) {
       return data;
   });
   return test;
   ```

But since node.js code works asynchronously, it wouldn't work. I believe some synchronous libraries might help, but what's the proper and elegant way to do it?

Thank you,

Tom

Answer (score 1):

You can just return promise and operate on this value out of the function

```
getRecent: function() {
    return models.download.find({}).sort({date_added: -1}).limit(5).exec();
}

getRecent().then(function(data) {
    // do something with data
});
```